# Integrating C++ video streaming application with django webframework

Tags: c++, django, video-streaming, ipc, opencv3.0

We are developing a simple video streaming application that will stream a single channel video over a private WiFi network.

The c++ application(using OpenCV) that does the video processing will reside on a Linux server.

The users will be able to view the videos live by logging on to the same Linux server using a web interface.

The number of users logging onto will be less than 10 at a time.

We would like to have the video streaming over the network to be encrypted.

The Linux server running the application(both c++ part and django webserver are on one machine) is a standard PC grade machine.

Here is a small block diagram

{(C++ Image/video processing)--->(webserver)}=====PrivateWifi========> Users(less than 10)

My questions are

**How do i send the video stream from C++ application to the Web server,Here i am planing to use Django webframework?**

**Is it a good way to use Django in this situation?What would be the correct way to do it?**

Pointers on **encrypting the video will be welcome**?

Comment: "encrypted" does't have meaningful in this context. What problem are you trying to solve where "encryption" is the solution. (Also, to maximize your results on stack overflow, ask one question per post. SO works well as question/answer, and poorly as a conversation)

Answer (score 0):

For broadcast quality streaming and if you can forgo Django, you can try CasparCG, an open source project for windows and Linux. The server version 2.07 supports streaming. Decklink, Bluefish, FFmpeg consumers are also supported. Try your luck here. Interface is pretty easy, for you have to establish just a socket to connect to the server.